# FtpClient.login() returns false to existing user

Tags: java, ftp-client

I'm trying to connect into FTP server, the problem is that wehn I try to log into the server with specific user it returns false.

This is the link for the ftp website: https://url.publishedprices.co.il/

The user name is: DorAlon
The password should be empty

When I'm connecting through the website it's working, it works too when i'm connecting from FileZilla, but when I do so from Java it returns false for this user. There are several more users that logged in successfully to this server, and only this user doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
    String server = "url.retail.publishedprices.co.il";
    int port = 21;
    String pass = " ";

    FtpClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    try {
        ftpClient.connect(server, port);
        boolean a = ftpClient.login("xxx", "");
        boolean b = ftpClient.login("yyy", "");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            // Checking whether the client is connected - in that case we'll logout and disconnect from the server 
            if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                ftpClient.logout();
                ftpClient.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

In the end the boolean a holds false, and b holds true.
It's mean the connection with the server is okay and also the login, but for the specific user it doesn't work.

How could this be possible?
I would like for some help, Thanks.

Comment: don't post credentials, even if it's just an example...

Comment: It's a public credentials for the comunity. My country shared it in public for people use.